# Random number range, exclude 0

Tags: c

I have the following function that generates a random number between -10 and 2:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static int
getRandomReturnCode(void)
{
    int N = 2,
        M = -10;

    srand(time(NULL));

    r = M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1);

    if (r == 0){
        getRandomReturnCode();
    }

    return r;
}
```

Currently, if a return code of 0 (success) is returned, it will recursively call the function over until a non-zero return code is met and returned. What can I do to improve my code such that 0 is excluded from the range of randomly chosen numbers?

Comment: Generate a number from -10 to 1 and if the value is 0 or 1, add one to it.

Comment: Don't call `srand` more than once. Put it in `main`.

Comment: Generate a number between 1 and 13? -13 and -1?

Comment: As a separate comment, note that your use of recursion is flawed, since you are making a recursive call to a function that returns a value, but you do not assign it, so if you get `r=0`, you will make a second call, discard the result, and return 0 anyway

Comment: Don't use rand() if you care about getting a good pseudorandom number stream. rand() is horribly flawed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whatever you do, **don't** redraw if a returned value is 0: that will introduce statistical bias into the result.

The best thing to do here is to draw between -10 and 1 inclusive and add 1 to any non-negative output.

Finally, call `srand` **once** else you'll ruin the generator's statistical properties.

(Briefly - since this comment is more for the mathematics site - and restricting the argument to a linear congruential generator, what tends to happen if you omit generated values is that you increase the variance of the resulting distribution so it's no longer uniform. A previously drawn small number will be linearly related to the subsequent drawing as the generator's modulus will have no effect. This autocorrelation - necessary for the resulting distribution to be uniform - of adjacent drawings will be curtailed if drawings are discarded and *that* increases the sample variance.)

Comment: Please explain (or cite a source). This seems counterintuitive (as many things do in this field).

Comment: The concern about not redrawing seems small compared to the unmentioned bias of `-10 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / 13 + 1)`.